# Save file directly to disk in ASP.NET without loading it into memory

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have an ASP.NET web application and I want my users to be able to upload large files. However, some files are very large and uses too much memory.

In principle it should be possible to receive the request stream and write it directly to a FileWriter stream, removing any need to load the entire file into memory first.

I've tried accessing `Request.InputStream` and writing it directly to a file. It works, but a test using larger files reveal that `Request.InputStream` is only available after the entire request is already loaded into memory.

Can someone tell me an approach I can use to receive a normal `Request.InputStream` in ASP.NET and directly write it to a file without first loading it into memory?

Note, the file is sent through a normal request in a browser by posting a form with a file field.
(I actually use [BlueImp JQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) but I don't think it's relevant to this question)

Comment: I believe this is a limitation of http protocol not .NET.

Comment: Do you mean that the protocol works so that you can only receive a complete request and cannot begin processing the request before the entire request has been received?

Comment: Yeah, but, I'm not able not find any authoritative information.

Answer (score 0):

The process is called **byte serving**.

> **[Byte Serving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving):**
>   Byte serving is the process of sending only a portion of an HTTP/1.1 message from a server to a client. Byte serving begins when an HTTP server advertises its willingness to serve partial requests using the Accept-Ranges response header. A client then requests a specific part of a file from the server using the Range request header.

Is seems that IIS and ASP.NET are capable of handling Accept-Range headers. There is a [Range Controller](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/23/asp-net-web-api-and-http-byte-range-support.aspx) on Microsoft git repositories.

Here is an [article](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/configure-byte-range-request-segment-size-in-application-request-routing) that may be useful in configuring IIS to handle these requests.

Comment: Im talking about letting the client send a file to the server. The description in your answer talks about the client accepting part of the response. So that doesnt seem to be the same thing.

Comment: Oh. You're right. Dummer. I'll keep searching for a solution.

Comment: An epiphany birth in bowels of the great fire wall: What do you think about allowing the user to pass a URL of file and using a wget-like function to download the file to the server?